How to prevent object overwriting in AWS S3?
I have the following IAM policy to allow read and write on a S3 bucket:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::yp-media"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::yio-media/Designs/Greeting_Cards/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}

This policy is also letting the user overwrite existing files.
I have activated the Object Lock option on this bucket but overwrites are still happening when the user with the above IAM policy uploads files via AWS console. I have tried including the following DENY statement but overwrites are still happening even though object lock is activated as seen in the screenshot:

{
            "Sid": "VisualEditor4",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketObjectLockConfiguration",
                "s3:GetObjectRetention",
                "s3:PutObjectRetention",
                "s3:PutBucketObjectLockConfiguration",
                "s3:PutObjectLegalHold",
                "s3:GetObjectLegalHold",
                "s3:BypassGovernanceRetention"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }

What changes should I make to this policy to prevent overwriting if object exists?

...why disallow overwriting files while allowing file deletion?

The policy is assigned to a user who doesn't have access to file deletion. However, the root user should be able to delete files if required and Object Lock will prevent that I guess.

Would it be sufficient to activate Versioning on the bucket so that any "overwriting" simply causes a new version of the object to be created, while retaining all previous versions? Would that meet your need to "prevent overwriting"?

Versioning won't solve the issue in my use case. I tried object locking and have updated the question with more info.

Object locks won't help, as you've seen, since they don't prevent new versions, just block removing and replacing specific versions.  S3 has no mechanism to prevent a PUT operation if an object already exists.  At best, you can only allow new objects to be created elsewhere, and have a process you control decide if it can move the object into place based on business logic.
